# How do I get python to load .NET .dlls referenced by mixed mode .dlls?

Tags: python, windows

I have a python .pyd that is a mixed mode C++ DLL.  The DLL loads fine and loads unmanaged C++ dlls without a problem, but when it tries to load the .NET dlls referenced by the managed C++ dlls it fails with this error message:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly '...'
```

Copying these .NET dlls to the directory that pythod_d.exe is contained in allows the .NET libraries to load successfully, but this is not a good long term solution.  Is there an environment variable I have to set or some command line option to python_d.exe that will solve  my problem?

Note that using IronPython or Python .NET is NOT acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've resolved the problem.  Assembly loading doesn't use the path set by SetDllDirectory(), and it looks like Python calls this function.  By registering a delegate for the event [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx), I can catch the name of the dll that failed, append it to the directory obtained from GetDllDirectory(), and then manually load the assembly myself.

Answer (score 0):

I have a little bit experience with this. I believe it's related to the path and init issues as stated in http://effbot.org/pyfaq/is-a-pyd-file-the-same-as-a-dll.htm.

Comment: We tried modifying PYTHONPATH but unfortunately that doesn't solve the problem.